# How to determine x- coordinate value when using Rule Mark in Vega chart

Tags: linechart, vega

I have implemented a line chart using Vega that has date values (timestamp) on X-axis and Count(Numeric value) on the y-axis. For transformation of data I am using `toDate(datum[\"dateTime\"])` expression. I want to plot a rule mark on the chart that has a specific timestamp value. I am able to draw it, but it accepts [image]numeric values for the x,y,x2,y2 coordinates, eg. 150,0,150,300 respectively. Now I have the timestamp as the input which is the point where I want to plot the vertical rule mark. Can anyone help me how to map a timestamp value to its corresponding x-coordinate value ?

Spec:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v4.json",
  "autosize": {"type": "pad", "resize": true},
  "padding": 5,
  "width": 1500,
  "height": 300,
  "style": "cell",
  "signals": [
    { "name": "x", "value": 150,
        "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 0, "max": 1554403500000, "step": 1} },
      { "name": "y", "value": 0,
        "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 0, "max": 1554403500000, "step": 1} },
      { "name": "x2", "value": 150,
        "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 0, "max": 200, "step": 1} },
      { "name": "y2", "value": 300,
        "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 0, "max": 200, "step": 1} },
      { "name": "strokeWidth", "value": 1 },
      { "name": "strokeCap", "value": "butt" },
      { "name": "strokeDash", "value": [4,4]
      },
    {
      "name": "clear",
      "value": true,
      "on": [
        {"events": "mouseup[!event.item]", "update": "true", "force": true}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "shift",
      "value": false,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "@legendSymbol:click, @legendLabel:click",
          "update": "event.shiftKey",
          "force": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "clicked",
      "value": null,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "@legendSymbol:click, @legendLabel:click",
          "update": "{value: datum.value}",
          "force": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "brush",
      "value": 0,
      "on": [
        {"events": {"signal": "clear"}, "update": "clear ? [0, 0] : brush"},
        {"events": "@xaxis:mousedown", "update": "[x(), x()]"},
        {
          "events": "[@xaxis:mousedown, window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "update": "[brush[0], clamp(x(), 0, width)]"
        },
        {
          "events": {"signal": "delta"},
          "update": "clampRange([anchor[0] + delta, anchor[1] + delta], 0, width)"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "anchor",
      "value": null,
      "on": [{"events": "@brush:mousedown", "update": "slice(brush)"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "xdown",
      "value": 0,
      "on": [{"events": "@brush:mousedown", "update": "x()"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "delta",
      "value": 0,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "[@brush:mousedown, window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "update": "x() - xdown"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "domain",
      "on": [
        {
          "events": {"signal": "brush"},
          "update": "span(brush) ? invert('x', brush) : null"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {"name": "table",  "values": [ 
   { 
      "dateTime":1554399600000,
      "count":69,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554399900000,
      "count":82,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554400200000,
      "count":24,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554400500000,
      "count":80,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554400800000,
      "count":34,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554401100000,
      "count":58,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554401400000,
      "count":33,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554401700000,
      "count":56,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554402000000,
      "count":98,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554402300000,
      "count":66,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554402600000,
      "count":22,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554402900000,
      "count":48,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554403200000,
      "count":89,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554403500000,
      "count":69,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554403800000,
      "count":94,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554404100000,
      "count":30,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554404400000,
      "count":66,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554404700000,
      "count":87,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554405000000,
      "count":99,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554405300000,
      "count":23,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554405600000,
      "count":49,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554405900000,
      "count":45,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554406200000,
      "count":90,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554406500000,
      "count":87,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554406800000,
      "count":69,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554407100000,
      "count":23,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554407400000,
      "count":60,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554407700000,
      "count":76,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554408000000,
      "count":82,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554408300000,
      "count":81,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554408600000,
      "count":76,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554408900000,
      "count":96,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554409200000,
      "count":46,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554409500000,
      "count":61,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554409800000,
      "count":59,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554410100000,
      "count":93,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554410400000,
      "count":48,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554410700000,
      "count":42,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554411000000,
      "count":76,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554411300000,
      "count":75,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554411600000,
      "count":43,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554411900000,
      "count":48,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554412200000,
      "count":20,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554412500000,
      "count":70,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554412800000,
      "count":25,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554413100000,
      "count":96,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554413400000,
      "count":70,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554413700000,
      "count":74,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554414000000,
      "count":89,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554414300000,
      "count":73,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554414600000,
      "count":78,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554414900000,
      "count":38,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554415200000,
      "count":49,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554415500000,
      "count":84,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554415800000,
      "count":27,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554416100000,
      "count":31,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554416400000,
      "count":63,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554416700000,
      "count":67,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554417000000,
      "count":63,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554417300000,
      "count":99,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554417600000,
      "count":75,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554417900000,
      "count":24,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554418200000,
      "count":95,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554418500000,
      "count":77,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554418800000,
      "count":38,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554419100000,
      "count":78,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554419400000,
      "count":99,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554419700000,
      "count":24,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554420000000,
      "count":79,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554420300000,
      "count":55,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554420600000,
      "count":22,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554420900000,
      "count":97,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554421200000,
      "count":83,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554421500000,
      "count":68,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554421800000,
      "count":28,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554422100000,
      "count":37,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   }
] },
    {
      "name": "data_0",
      "source": "table",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "toDate(datum[\"dateTime\"])",
          "as": "dateTime"
        },
        {
          "type": "window",
          "params": [null],
          "as": ["rank"],
          "ops": ["rank"],
          "fields": [null],
          "sort": {"field": ["dateTime"], "order": ["descending"]}
        },
        {"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.rank <= 10000"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "data_1",
      "source": "data_0",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "dateTime",
          "expr": "toDate(datum[\"dateTime\"])"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "data_2",
      "source": "data_0",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "if(datum.outlier == true, datum.count, null)",
          "as": "count"
        },
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "true", "as": "baseline"},
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "dateTime",
          "expr": "toDate(datum[\"dateTime\"])"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "data_3",
      "source": "data_0",
      "transform": [
        {"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.outlier == true"},
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "true", "as": "baseline"},
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "dateTime",
          "expr": "toDate(datum[\"dateTime\"])"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "selected",
      "on": [
        {"trigger": "clear", "remove": true},
        {"trigger": "!shift", "remove": true},
        {"trigger": "!shift && clicked", "insert": "clicked"},
        {"trigger": "shift && clicked", "toggle": "clicked"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
    "type": "rule",
    "encode": {
      "enter": {
        "stroke": {"value": "red"}
      },
      "update": {
        "x": {"signal": "x"},
        "y": {"signal": "y"},
        "x2": {"signal": "x2"},
        "y2": {"signal": "y2"},
        "strokeWidth": {"signal": "strokeWidth"},
        "strokeDash": {"signal": "strokeDash"},
        "strokeCap": {"signal": "strokeCap"},
        "opacity": {"value": 1}
      },
      "hover": {
        "opacity": {"value": 0.5}
      }
    }
  },
    {
      "name": "layer_0_pathgroup",
      "type": "group",
      "from": {
        "facet": {
          "name": "faceted_path_layer_0_main",
          "data": "data_1",
          "groupby": ["category", "category"]
        }
      },
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "width": {"field": {"group": "width"}},
          "height": {"field": {"group": "height"}}
        }
      },
      "marks": [
        {
          "name": "layer_0_marks",
          "type": "line",
          "style": ["line"],
          "sort": {"field": "datum[\"dateTime\"]", "order": "descending"},
          "from": {"data": "faceted_path_layer_0_main"},
          "encode": {
            "update": {
              "opacity": [
                {
                  "test": "(!domain || inrange(datum.dateTime, domain)) && (!length(data('selected')) || indata('selected', 'value', datum.category))",
                  "value": 0.7
                },
                {"value": 0.15}
              ],
              "stroke": [
                {
                  "test": "(!domain || inrange(datum.dateTime, domain)) && (!length(data('selected')) || indata('selected', 'value', datum.category))",
                  "scale": "color",
                  "field": "category"
                },
                {"value": "#ccc"}
              ],
              "tooltip": {
                "signal": "{\"Time\": timeFormat(datum[\"dateTime\"], '%b %d, %Y %H:%M'), \"Count\": format(datum[\"count\"], \"\"), \"category\": ''+datum[\"category\"]}"
              },
              "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "dateTime"},
              "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "count"},
              "defined": {
                "signal": "datum[\"dateTime\"] !== null && !isNaN(datum[\"dateTime\"]) && datum[\"count\"] !== null && !isNaN(datum[\"count\"])"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "layer_1_pathgroup",
      "type": "group",
      "from": {
        "facet": {
          "name": "faceted_path_layer_1_main",
          "data": "data_2",
          "groupby": ["category"]
        }
      },
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "width": {"field": {"group": "width"}},
          "height": {"field": {"group": "height"}}
        }
      },
      "marks": [
        {
          "name": "layer_1_marks",
          "type": "line",
          "style": ["line"],
          "sort": {"field": "datum[\"dateTime\"]", "order": "descending"},
          "from": {"data": "faceted_path_layer_1_main"},
          "encode": {
            "update": {
              "stroke": {"value": "red"},
              "opacity": [
                {
                  "test": "(!domain || inrange(datum.dateTime, domain)) && (!length(data('selected')) || indata('selected', 'value', datum.category))",
                  "value": 0.7
                },
                {"value": 0.15}
              ],
              "tooltip": {
                "signal": "{\"Time\": timeFormat(datum[\"dateTime\"], '%b %d, %Y %H:%M'), \"Count\": format(datum[\"count\"], \"\"), \"category\": ''+datum[\"category\"]}"
              },
              "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "dateTime"},
              "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "count"},
              "defined": {
                "signal": "datum[\"dateTime\"] !== null && !isNaN(datum[\"dateTime\"]) && datum[\"count\"] !== null && !isNaN(datum[\"count\"])"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "layer_2_marks",
      "type": "symbol",
      "style": ["circle"],
      "from": {"data": "data_3"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "opacity": [
            {
              "test": "(!domain || inrange(datum.dateTime, domain)) && (!length(data('selected')) || indata('selected', 'value', datum.category))",
              "value": 0.7
            },
            {"value": 0.15}
          ],
          "fill": [
            {
              "test": "datum[\"dateTime\"] === null || isNaN(datum[\"dateTime\"]) || datum[\"count\"] === null || isNaN(datum[\"count\"])",
              "value": null
            },
            {"value": "red"}
          ],
          "tooltip": {
            "signal": "{\"Time\": timeFormat(datum[\"dateTime\"], '%b %d, %Y %H:%M'), \"Count\": format(datum[\"count\"], \"\"), \"category\": ''+datum[\"category\"]}"
          },
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "dateTime"},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "count"},
          "shape": {"value": "circle"}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "time",
      "domain": {
        "fields": [
          {"data": "data_1", "field": "dateTime"},
          {"data": "data_2", "field": "dateTime"},
          {"data": "data_3", "field": "dateTime"}
        ]
      },
      "range": [0, {"signal": "width"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": {
        "fields": [
          {"data": "data_1", "field": "count"},
          {"data": "data_2", "field": "count"},
          {"data": "data_3", "field": "count"}
        ]
      },
      "range": [{"signal": "height"}, 0],
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "data_1", "field": "category", "sort": true},
      "range": {"scheme": "tableau20"}
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {
      "scale": "x",
      "orient": "bottom",
      "grid": false,
      "title": "Time",
      "titleColor":"black",
      "labelColor":"black",
      "labelFlush": true,
      "labelOverlap": true,
      "tickCount": {"signal": "ceil(width/40)"},
      "encode": {
        "labels": {
          "update": {
            "text": {"signal": "timeFormat(datum.value, '%b %d, %Y %H:%M')"}
          }
        }
      },
      "zindex": 1
    },
    {
      "scale": "y",
      "orient": "left",
      "grid": false,
      "titleColor":"black",
      "labelColor":"black",
      "title": "Count",
      "labelOverlap": true,
      "tickCount": {"signal": "ceil(height/40)"},
      "zindex": 1
    }
  ],
  "legends": [
    {
      "stroke": "color",
      "orient": "top-left",
      "title": "React Vega",
      "titleColor":"black",
      "labelColor":"black",
      "encode": {
        "symbols": {
          "name": "legendSymbol",
          "interactive": true,
          "update": {
            "fill": {"value": "transparent"},
            "strokeWidth": {"value": 2},
            "opacity": [
              {
                "test": "!length(data('selected')) || indata('selected', 'value', datum.value)",
                "value": 0.7
              },
              {"value": 0.15}
            ],
            "size": {"value": 64}
          }
        },
        "labels": {
          "name": "legendLabel",
          "interactive": true,
          "update": {
            "opacity": [
              {
                "test": "!length(data('selected')) || indata('selected', 'value', datum.value)",
                "value": 1
              },
              {"value": 0.25}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {"axisY": {"minExtent": 30}}
}
```

I have added an image of the rule mark for reference.

Answer (score 3):

To translate data to pixel values, you can map it through a scale.

[image: chart for the given spec]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v4.json",
  "autosize": {"type": "pad", "resize": true},
  "padding": 5,
  "width": 1500,
  "height": 300,
  "style": "cell",
  "signals": [
    { "name": "x", "value": 1554418500000,
        "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 0, "max": 1554403500000, "step": 1} },
      { "name": "y", "value": 0,
        "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 0, "max": 1554403500000, "step": 1} },
      { "name": "x2", "value": 1554418500000,
        "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 0, "max": 200, "step": 1} },
      { "name": "y2", "value": 300,
        "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 0, "max": 200, "step": 1} },
      { "name": "strokeWidth", "value": 1 },
      { "name": "strokeCap", "value": "butt" },
      { "name": "strokeDash", "value": [4,4]
      },
    {
      "name": "clear",
      "value": true,
      "on": [
        {"events": "mouseup[!event.item]", "update": "true", "force": true}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "shift",
      "value": false,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "@legendSymbol:click, @legendLabel:click",
          "update": "event.shiftKey",
          "force": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "clicked",
      "value": null,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "@legendSymbol:click, @legendLabel:click",
          "update": "{value: datum.value}",
          "force": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "brush",
      "value": 0,
      "on": [
        {"events": {"signal": "clear"}, "update": "clear ? [0, 0] : brush"},
        {"events": "@xaxis:mousedown", "update": "[x(), x()]"},
        {
          "events": "[@xaxis:mousedown, window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "update": "[brush[0], clamp(x(), 0, width)]"
        },
        {
          "events": {"signal": "delta"},
          "update": "clampRange([anchor[0] + delta, anchor[1] + delta], 0, width)"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "anchor",
      "value": null,
      "on": [{"events": "@brush:mousedown", "update": "slice(brush)"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "xdown",
      "value": 0,
      "on": [{"events": "@brush:mousedown", "update": "x()"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "delta",
      "value": 0,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "[@brush:mousedown, window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "update": "x() - xdown"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "domain",
      "on": [
        {
          "events": {"signal": "brush"},
          "update": "span(brush) ? invert('x', brush) : null"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {"name": "table",  "values": [ 
   { 
      "dateTime":1554399600000,
      "count":69,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554399900000,
      "count":82,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554400200000,
      "count":24,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554400500000,
      "count":80,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554400800000,
      "count":34,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554401100000,
      "count":58,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554401400000,
      "count":33,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554401700000,
      "count":56,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554402000000,
      "count":98,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554402300000,
      "count":66,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554402600000,
      "count":22,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554402900000,
      "count":48,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554403200000,
      "count":89,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554403500000,
      "count":69,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554403800000,
      "count":94,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554404100000,
      "count":30,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554404400000,
      "count":66,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554404700000,
      "count":87,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554405000000,
      "count":99,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554405300000,
      "count":23,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554405600000,
      "count":49,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554405900000,
      "count":45,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554406200000,
      "count":90,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554406500000,
      "count":87,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554406800000,
      "count":69,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554407100000,
      "count":23,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554407400000,
      "count":60,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554407700000,
      "count":76,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554408000000,
      "count":82,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554408300000,
      "count":81,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554408600000,
      "count":76,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554408900000,
      "count":96,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554409200000,
      "count":46,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554409500000,
      "count":61,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554409800000,
      "count":59,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554410100000,
      "count":93,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554410400000,
      "count":48,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554410700000,
      "count":42,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554411000000,
      "count":76,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554411300000,
      "count":75,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554411600000,
      "count":43,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554411900000,
      "count":48,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554412200000,
      "count":20,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554412500000,
      "count":70,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554412800000,
      "count":25,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554413100000,
      "count":96,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554413400000,
      "count":70,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554413700000,
      "count":74,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554414000000,
      "count":89,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554414300000,
      "count":73,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554414600000,
      "count":78,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554414900000,
      "count":38,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554415200000,
      "count":49,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554415500000,
      "count":84,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554415800000,
      "count":27,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554416100000,
      "count":31,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554416400000,
      "count":63,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554416700000,
      "count":67,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554417000000,
      "count":63,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554417300000,
      "count":99,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554417600000,
      "count":75,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554417900000,
      "count":24,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554418200000,
      "count":95,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554418500000,
      "count":77,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554418800000,
      "count":38,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554419100000,
      "count":78,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554419400000,
      "count":99,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554419700000,
      "count":24,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554420000000,
      "count":79,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554420300000,
      "count":55,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554420600000,
      "count":22,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554420900000,
      "count":97,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554421200000,
      "count":83,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554421500000,
      "count":68,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554421800000,
      "count":28,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   },
   { 
      "dateTime":1554422100000,
      "count":37,
      "outlier":false,
      "category":"React Vega",
      "id":0
   }
] },
    {
      "name": "data_0",
      "source": "table",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "toDate(datum[\"dateTime\"])",
          "as": "dateTime"
        },
        {
          "type": "window",
          "params": [null],
          "as": ["rank"],
          "ops": ["rank"],
          "fields": [null],
          "sort": {"field": ["dateTime"], "order": ["descending"]}
        },
        {"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.rank <= 10000"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "data_1",
      "source": "data_0",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "dateTime",
          "expr": "toDate(datum[\"dateTime\"])"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "data_2",
      "source": "data_0",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "if(datum.outlier == true, datum.count, null)",
          "as": "count"
        },
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "true", "as": "baseline"},
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "dateTime",
          "expr": "toDate(datum[\"dateTime\"])"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "data_3",
      "source": "data_0",
      "transform": [
        {"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.outlier == true"},
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "true", "as": "baseline"},
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "dateTime",
          "expr": "toDate(datum[\"dateTime\"])"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "selected",
      "on": [
        {"trigger": "clear", "remove": true},
        {"trigger": "!shift", "remove": true},
        {"trigger": "!shift && clicked", "insert": "clicked"},
        {"trigger": "shift && clicked", "toggle": "clicked"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
    "type": "rule",
    "encode": {
      "enter": {
        "stroke": {"value": "red"}
      },
      "update": {
        "x": {"signal": "x", "scale": "x"},
        "y": {"signal": "y"},
        "x2": {"signal": "x2", "scale": "x"},
        "y2": {"signal": "y2"},
        "strokeWidth": {"signal": "strokeWidth"},
        "strokeDash": {"signal": "strokeDash"},
        "strokeCap": {"signal": "strokeCap"},
        "opacity": {"value": 1}
      },
      "hover": {
        "opacity": {"value": 0.5}
      }
    }
  },
    {
      "name": "layer_0_pathgroup",
      "type": "group",
      "from": {
        "facet": {
          "name": "faceted_path_layer_0_main",
          "data": "data_1",
          "groupby": ["category", "category"]
        }
      },
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "width": {"field": {"group": "width"}},
          "height": {"field": {"group": "height"}}
        }
      },
      "marks": [
        {
          "name": "layer_0_marks",
          "type": "line",
          "style": ["line"],
          "sort": {"field": "datum[\"dateTime\"]", "order": "descending"},
          "from": {"data": "faceted_path_layer_0_main"},
          "encode": {
            "update": {
              "opacity": [
                {
                  "test": "(!domain || inrange(datum.dateTime, domain)) && (!length(data('selected')) || indata('selected', 'value', datum.category))",
                  "value": 0.7
                },
                {"value": 0.15}
              ],
              "stroke": [
                {
                  "test": "(!domain || inrange(datum.dateTime, domain)) && (!length(data('selected')) || indata('selected', 'value', datum.category))",
                  "scale": "color",
                  "field": "category"
                },
                {"value": "#ccc"}
              ],
              "tooltip": {
                "signal": "{\"Time\": timeFormat(datum[\"dateTime\"], '%b %d, %Y %H:%M'), \"Count\": format(datum[\"count\"], \"\"), \"category\": ''+datum[\"category\"]}"
              },
              "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "dateTime"},
              "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "count"},
              "defined": {
                "signal": "datum[\"dateTime\"] !== null && !isNaN(datum[\"dateTime\"]) && datum[\"count\"] !== null && !isNaN(datum[\"count\"])"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "layer_1_pathgroup",
      "type": "group",
      "from": {
        "facet": {
          "name": "faceted_path_layer_1_main",
          "data": "data_2",
          "groupby": ["category"]
        }
      },
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "width": {"field": {"group": "width"}},
          "height": {"field": {"group": "height"}}
        }
      },
      "marks": [
        {
          "name": "layer_1_marks",
          "type": "line",
          "style": ["line"],
          "sort": {"field": "datum[\"dateTime\"]", "order": "descending"},
          "from": {"data": "faceted_path_layer_1_main"},
          "encode": {
            "update": {
              "stroke": {"value": "red"},
              "opacity": [
                {
                  "test": "(!domain || inrange(datum.dateTime, domain)) && (!length(data('selected')) || indata('selected', 'value', datum.category))",
                  "value": 0.7
                },
                {"value": 0.15}
              ],
              "tooltip": {
                "signal": "{\"Time\": timeFormat(datum[\"dateTime\"], '%b %d, %Y %H:%M'), \"Count\": format(datum[\"count\"], \"\"), \"category\": ''+datum[\"category\"]}"
              },
              "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "dateTime"},
              "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "count"},
              "defined": {
                "signal": "datum[\"dateTime\"] !== null && !isNaN(datum[\"dateTime\"]) && datum[\"count\"] !== null && !isNaN(datum[\"count\"])"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "layer_2_marks",
      "type": "symbol",
      "style": ["circle"],
      "from": {"data": "data_3"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "opacity": [
            {
              "test": "(!domain || inrange(datum.dateTime, domain)) && (!length(data('selected')) || indata('selected', 'value', datum.category))",
              "value": 0.7
            },
            {"value": 0.15}
          ],
          "fill": [
            {
              "test": "datum[\"dateTime\"] === null || isNaN(datum[\"dateTime\"]) || datum[\"count\"] === null || isNaN(datum[\"count\"])",
              "value": null
            },
            {"value": "red"}
          ],
          "tooltip": {
            "signal": "{\"Time\": timeFormat(datum[\"dateTime\"], '%b %d, %Y %H:%M'), \"Count\": format(datum[\"count\"], \"\"), \"category\": ''+datum[\"category\"]}"
          },
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "dateTime"},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "count"},
          "shape": {"value": "circle"}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "time",
      "domain": {
        "fields": [
          {"data": "data_1", "field": "dateTime"},
          {"data": "data_2", "field": "dateTime"},
          {"data": "data_3", "field": "dateTime"}
        ]
      },
      "range": [0, {"signal": "width"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": {
        "fields": [
          {"data": "data_1", "field": "count"},
          {"data": "data_2", "field": "count"},
          {"data": "data_3", "field": "count"}
        ]
      },
      "range": [{"signal": "height"}, 0],
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "data_1", "field": "category", "sort": true},
      "range": {"scheme": "tableau20"}
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {
      "scale": "x",
      "orient": "bottom",
      "grid": false,
      "title": "Time",
      "titleColor":"black",
      "labelColor":"black",
      "labelFlush": true,
      "labelOverlap": true,
      "tickCount": {"signal": "ceil(width/40)"},
      "encode": {
        "labels": {
          "update": {
            "text": {"signal": "timeFormat(datum.value, '%b %d, %Y %H:%M')"}
          }
        }
      },
      "zindex": 1
    },
    {
      "scale": "y",
      "orient": "left",
      "grid": false,
      "titleColor":"black",
      "labelColor":"black",
      "title": "Count",
      "labelOverlap": true,
      "tickCount": {"signal": "ceil(height/40)"},
      "zindex": 1
    }
  ],
  "legends": [
    {
      "stroke": "color",
      "orient": "top-left",
      "title": "React Vega",
      "titleColor":"black",
      "labelColor":"black",
      "encode": {
        "symbols": {
          "name": "legendSymbol",
          "interactive": true,
          "update": {
            "fill": {"value": "transparent"},
            "strokeWidth": {"value": 2},
            "opacity": [
              {
                "test": "!length(data('selected')) || indata('selected', 'value', datum.value)",
                "value": 0.7
              },
              {"value": 0.15}
            ],
            "size": {"value": 64}
          }
        },
        "labels": {
          "name": "legendLabel",
          "interactive": true,
          "update": {
            "opacity": [
              {
                "test": "!length(data('selected')) || indata('selected', 'value', datum.value)",
                "value": 1
              },
              {"value": 0.25}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {"axisY": {"minExtent": 30}}
}
```